# How to upgrade core 2.1.1 to core 2.2.3

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

The official documentation does not work.
Do I need VS 2017 Preview?! Or to restart my pc every time I install "Latest stable 2.2.3" SDK's? Perhaps its not so stable? Should I try 2.2.1 lol

Comment: What have you tried exactly? Did you follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio? What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

VS 2015 will work up for up to .NET Core 1.1 (now EOL). VS 2017 will work for up to .NET Core 2.2. .NET Core 3.0+ requires VS 2019.

It's not clear what your exact issue is, but the process is basically this:

1. Download the appropriate .NET Core SDK version. Be careful because the SDK version is somewhat independent of the .NET Core version. Pay attention to specifically what version of .NET Core the SDK supports, not the version number of the SDK itself.
2. Edit your project file and change the target to the new .NET Core version. This will be the minor version, not patch releates. In other words, for any .NET Core 2.2.X, you'd use `netcoreapp2.2` as your target.

That's it. After you save, any NuGet dependencies of your project, such as `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` will update to the latest version within that target, i.e. 2.2.X. However, note that some packages may not always have new versions. Most of the major parts of ASP.NET Core, for example, change enough with each version that the NuGet packages get bumped as well. However, it is possible that you may still use a 2.1.X package if nothing changed in that for 2.2. In any case, you'll be able to see in Visual Studio if it's fully updated or not.

Comment: BTW, VS2015 does not support .NET Core 1.x officially. .NET Core 1.0 and 1.1 all require VS2017.

Comment: @LexLi: No, you could develop 1.X in VS 2015. Although, it hardly matters, since it's EOL.